# display table group by category using php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

my database design is like this

```
-- Table Reason
--------------------------
| reasonid  | reasonname |
--------------------------
|    1      |  reason1   |
|    2      |  reason2   |
--------------------------
-- Table Student
----------------------------
| studentid  | studentname |
----------------------------
|    1      |     John     |
|    2      |     Jane     |
|    3      |     Hulk     |
----------------------------
-- Table form
-----------------------------------
| formid  | studentid |  reasonid |
-----------------------------------
|    1    |     1     |     1     |
|    2    |     2     |     2     |
|    3    |     3     |     1     |
-----------------------------------
```

I want to show data table like :

```
reason1
| 1  |  John  |
| 2  |  Hulk  |
reason2
| 1  |  Jane  |
```

I have tried below code but the result is not groupBy reason

```
<?php $i =1;
      while($rowfet = mysql_fetch_array($myselect)){ ?>
            <h2><?php echo $rowfet['ReasonName']; ?></h2>
            <table>
            <thead>
                <tr class="active">
                <th>No.</th>
                <th>StudentName</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                <td align="center"><?php echo $i; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $rowfet['STUDENTNAME']; ?></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>
        <?php $i++; } ?>
```

the result of this code is :

```
reason1
|  1  |  John |
reason1
|  2  |  Hulk |
reason2
|  3  |  Jane |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

outside while loop:

```
$lastReasonId = '';
```

inside while loop:

```
if($rowfet['reasonid'] != $lastReasonId){
    // show heading
}
$lastReasonId = $rowfet['reasonid'];
```

But your code is far from ok. The $i++ thing is not doing anything, you should probably echo $rowfet['studentid'] there.
And you are using deprecated mysql code.